# Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, flutter-web

**Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome. This can happen if the websocket connection used by the web tooling is unable to correctly establish a connection, , for example due to a firewallfor example due to a firewall.**

i am getting this error whenever i run flutter web application on chrome in debug mode. i disable firewall and still not working, but when i run it in release mode its work. can anyone help me please! i am using window 8.1 64bit

Answer (score 3):

What seems to solve the issue is running the following commands inside your flutter project directory:

flutter clean

flutter run -d chrome --release

After running the first time in the release mode, you can then run in the debug mode with just:

flutter run -d chrome

Reference:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49482

Comment: perfect  , thank you Carlos ( why flutter do this strange error?) are this as a refresh (but more heavy)

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me ( no firewall issue, no Dart Debug Extension installed )

➜  somefolder flutter run -d chrome

Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...            125.9s

***Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome.
This can happen if the websocket connection used by the web tooling is unable to correctly establish a connection, for
example due to a firewall.***

➜  somefolder flutter clean

Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                        39.2s
Deleting build...                                                  712ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              97ms
Deleting .packages...                                                0ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                      16ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms

➜  somefolder flutter devices

1 connected device:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.128

➜  somefolder flutter run -d chrome --release

Running "flutter pub get" in somefolder...                         10.8s
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in release mode...
Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                             38.3s

To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".

Performing hot restart...                                           5.5s
Restarted application in 5,489ms.

Performing hot restart...                                          394ms
Restarted application in 394ms.

Performing hot restart...                                          375ms
Restarted application in 375ms.

Application finished.

➜  somefolder flutter run -d chrome

Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             37.9s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64242/GMDUxFrKo2U=/ws

Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".

Answer (score 0):

You need not to disable firewall,
You have to download Dart Debug Extension on Google Chrome then  run
flutter app on web